# Difference between $$ and $

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototypejs, prototype

**what is Difference between "$$" and "$"?**

```
$$('#items li').each( function(item) {
  item.observe('click', function(event) {
    doSomethingWith(event.target);
  });
});
```

==========================

```
$('items').observe('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    doSomethingWith(event.target);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Prototype.js documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/)

`$` — id (String | Element) — A DOM node or a string that references a node's ID

`$$(cssRule...)` — Takes an arbitrary number of CSS selectors (strings) and returns a document-order array of extended DOM elements that match any of them.